# Проверка checkbox для чайника

Tags: jquery, javascript, checkbox

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Есть чекбокс, при отметке которого нужно выполнить действие:

```
return categoryFilter('other1','1')
```

Если отметку убирают, нужно выполнить:

```
return categoryFilter('other1','')
```

Как реализовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
   if(this.checked) {
      categoryFilter('other1','1');
   }
   else {
      categoryFilter('other1','');
   }
});
```

обновление

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
   var id = this.getAttribute('id');

   if(id == undefined) return;

   if(this.checked) {
      categoryFilter('other' + id, id);
   }
   else {
      categoryFilter('other' + id,'');
   }
});
```

Comment: ой как быстро ответили, спасибо не ожидал!))

я не совсем полностью описал задачу, таких чекбоксов 6, у каждого свой id как это сюда прикрутить?)) простите пожалуйста за тупость ((

Comment: @Dimastik86 данный скрипт будет работать со всеми чек боксами.

Comment: это я понял, просто для каждого чекбокса свое действие:
1 - categoryFilter('other1','1');
2 - categoryFilter('other2','2');
3 - categoryFilter('other3','3');
и тд

Comment: @Dimastik86 обновил пост.

Comment: спасибо тебе добрый человек! удачи тебе!

Comment: @Dimastik86 спасибо!) И вам удачи!